# Django admin interface adds characters u"[ ] to a list of strings with SeparatedValuesField

Tags: python, django, csv, django-admin

I'm using SeparatedValuesField to keep track of a list of strings as explained by http://davidcramer.posterous.com/code/181/custom-fields-in-django.html and many posts here on SO that recommend this as the right way to store a list of strings.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    device_ids = SeparatedValuesField(blank=True, null=True, default=[])
```

It is working fine in my application, I can add device ids and view them in the admin interface as expected.

```
user_profile.device_ids = ['666666-D849-524F-6984-7E9B2D768546']
```

But the problem is in the admin interface, when I open up the detail page for a UserProfile object, the admin interface itself is adding extra values to my device_ids field.

For example, my application inserts a value into the field, and when I view it in the admin interface it looks like this:

```
[u'666666-D849-524F-6984-7E9B2D768546']
```

Then I change some other random property on my UserProfile object and save it using the built in django admin interface save button.

When I open the UserProfile object detail page up again for my object, that value now looks like this:

```
[u"[u'666666-D849-524F-6984-7E9B2D768546']"]
```

If I repeat this process of just hitting save then opening up this detail page, it will continue nesting the actual value with u"[   ] characters.

Is there something I can do to change this functionality? Should I be storing the list of strings in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem, and finally figured it out thanks to these two [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199230/display-json-text-as-a-friendly-list-in-django-admin) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176613/django-admin-using-a-custom-widget-for-one-field).

What you need in this situation is a custom widget that renders the list of strings as a string. This widget needs to be tied to the custom field:

```
class FlattenListWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if not value is None:
            value = ','.join(str(v) for v in value)
        return super(FlattenListWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)

class UserProfileAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        widgets = {
            'device_ids': FlattenListWidget(),
        }

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserProfileAdminForm
```

Hope that works. I had different model names in my code but managed to get a text input containing a comma separated list of values from my custom field.

If you want to join the strings with a comma *and* a space `value = ', '.join(str(v) for v in value)`, remember to `strip()` the value in the custom field's `get_db_prep_value` method. Otherwise the spaces will be saved back to database.

To use the custom field in `list_display` you can add a custom field to the admin model:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserProfileAdminForm

    list_display = ('ids_list',)
    def ids_list(self, obj):
        if obj.device_ids:
            return ', '.join(str(i) for i in obj.device_ids)
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Oiva Eskola's answer looks fine (haven't tried it, though).

Finding the Django source before this question, I also stumbled upon the following (which works):

```
SeparatedValuesField(models.TextField):
    # ...

    def value_from_object(self, obj):
        return self.get_db_prep_value(super(SeparatedValuesField, self).value_from_object(obj))
```

Comment: This worked for me but i needed to add `connection=None` in `get_db_prep_value`